# 3rd party cookies in an iOS6 UIWebView

Tags: cookies, uiwebview, ios6

Our iOS app displays our website in a UIWebView.  The webview contains an iframe to a 3rd party site.  The 3rd party site requires the ability to set a cookie to store session information.  This seems to work properly in iOS 5, but not in iOS 6

Does anyone know of a workaround to or correct way to handle the setting of 3rd party cookies via a webview in iOS 6?

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem but it turned out that it looked like the default cookieAcceptPolicy has changed. This fixed it for me:

```
  [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage].cookieAcceptPolicy = NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways;
```